# Is this possible to group the in-repo engines under lib folder? Example: lib/group1/engine1...etc

Tags: ember.js, ember-engines

Is this possible to group certain in-repo engines under lib folder? Example: lib/group1/engines
lib/group2/engines

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by creating multiple in repo engines. Presuming your working directory is an ember application with the `ember-engines` package installed:

`$ ember generate in-repo-engine group1
$ ember generate in-repo-engine group1`

Be aware that [linking between them](https://github.com/ember-engines/ember-engines/issues/423) is not necessarily supported.
The official guide has the best explanation for [creating them.](http://ember-engines.com/guide/creating-an-engine) Based on the core team member's response in the first link, I think the best practice is to create engines as independent ember addons.

Comment: Thank u for ur reply. Here my question is, is there any way to group engines under a folder. Let's say, i have 4 in-repo-engines namely A, B, C1 and C2. I want to group C1 and C2 in-repo-engines under a folder called C (Folders - lib>> C>> C1 , lib>> C>> C2).Is this possible? If so, what are the other configurations we must do?

Comment: @JKP Sure thing. From what I linked above, I don't think that is supported; however, engines are still being actively developed. Because of this and that it is an open source project and welcoming community, I would recommend joining the ember slack and asking in the dedicated engines room: https://embercommunity.slack.com/